# What are good reasons to reduce contrast?

Tags: color-theory, contrast

Background information:

Hi. I'm in discussion with our marketing regarding a picture. Since I found a typo, they need to redo the image anyways, so I have some additional feedback for them.

The picture in question is this:

[image: Picture with little contrast]

The intended use is Instagram, hence the square shape. IMHO, the contrast is too low. The picture only uses 36% of the possible contrast. Even with the vintage content, I expect something else and I will make a proposal to them.

I don't want to know why the picture is bad. I also don't want to know how to improve the picture.

The question:

**What are good reasons and good use cases to reduce contrast in an image?** I've increased contrast and saturation in pictures a lot of times, but I currently can't recall a situation when I reduced contrast. **When would I do that and why?**

Comment: Tag suggestions and corrections are welcome. I'm not overly familiar with tags on this site.

Comment: What I find weirdest is the tag 'in 2010' against a backdrop of mid-80s computing ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: yes, that's also something to be changed. It is a picture somewhere between 1983 (when the company was founded) and 1990 (before the company relocated).

Comment: The text in the example doesn't have enough contrast with the photograph.  It's on the verge of being unreadable.

Comment: not asked, but consider breaking the lines manually. Just hitting the "align center" button is not usually good design.

Comment: The photo should have low contrast as a background photo. The text should have high contrast as intended to be read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One designer's aesthetics are rarely the same as another. `:)`

There are *many* instances where I've reduced contrast in photos when they are to be used more as "mood" or background, as opposed to focusing on a subject. There's certainly no harm in reducing photo contrast *if* it fits the aesthetic one is trying to achieve.

Low contrast images go a long way to conveying a "mood", a lack of clarity, a sense of mystery in some instances. There are very good reasons to reduce contrast at times.

---

For *this* image...

I think Lucian may be close with his answer -- Possibly to convey a "retro" mood and so text is more readable, but then.....

The value of the orange makes it *barely* readable. The *value* of the orange is a horrible choice — not the *hue*, the value. Orange makes sense, but a brighter orange would be better. And really... I could see reducing contrast in the photo another 10-20%.

The problem with the overall image is not necessarily the low contrast background photo. The problem is the overall value of the photo is almost identical to the value of the type.

Greyscale it... type gets lost..

[image]

Reduce by 20% to simulate seeing it at arms length...

[image]

The low contrast photo isn't the issue.. the matching type value is where things fail. To be more easily legible in passing (a la insta).. the text should be the brightest thing in greyscale. Here, it's exceptionally close the guys shirt, the computer casing, etc. One *could* go dark for the text, but that presents (to me) too many issue with dark areas of the photo.

Adding 25% more neutral grey to photo and keeping type the same ... shows how reducing contrast in the photo *more* better achieves acceptable readability.

(Original on left for comparison)

[image]

- Type pulled from original - quickly via color selection - to a new layer
- Additional new layer above photo filled 50% neutral grey
- Set blending mode of grey layer to Multiply
- Reduced grey layer to 50% opacity (really *any* opacity value works - just a matter of preference here).
- Type layer placed at the top of the layer stack

Comment: I think the value of the orange can't be discussed, as it's a CI/CD color. I'll suggest a soft shadow (black or white IDK yet) to get a better readability.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Reduce photo contrast another 10-20% the text will "pop" more and the photo will still be "readable". Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific image, they probably reduced contrast so that the overlaid text can still be slightly legible (with a full contrast image you would not be able to read the text). But this can be resolved in a number of other ways, in my opinion whoever designed this can probably do a better job, also that photo seems to be in very poor quality.

If this is posted in Instagram, that entire text can be pasted in the post description and removed from the picture, or summarized for better legibility (use limited wording on the picture, put the full text in the post text area).

Answer (score 3):

No comment about the pokey office and 30 years old equipment.

As said in other answers, the text vs background contrast is too low. You can prove it as numbers by having an on-screen color contrast analyzer. In the next version the image is corrected by inserting in  Photoshop a curves adjustment layer to lift contrast and a Hue/saturation adjustment layer to boost the orange:

[image: Color contrast analyzer screenshot]

The orange is measured against the lightest background point. It just exceeds the level AA minimum 4,5 : 1 but it's still bad for people who have sight problems.

The shown [color contrast analyzer](https://www.tpgi.com/cca-download/) is freeware.

You asked a good reason. One such reason is to make some overlaid item - like the text - more visible. But that's useful only if only the background is made dull, a good contrast must be kept between the BG and the overlay. I fixed it by stretching the dark end levels of the BG image darker and changing the orange text brighter.

The limitations of sRGB color system prevent me having stronger orange. If that's needed the BG must be even darker for good text vs BG contrast.